# Does spark provide priority mailbox like akka does

Tags: apache-spark, akka, akka-stream

As it is explained [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/java/mailboxes.html#prioritymailbox), akka provides different type of priority mailboxes which helps if you want to process some type of message before other types. I didn't found similar feature in spark documentation, Is there similar support available in apache-spark or how can similar behaviour be achieved?